# Swift firebase when retrieving data from the database, how to delay the next code until the retrieval is done?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, delay

I am working with a Firebase Real Time database and I am having troubles with the execution of code at specific times. When I ask the database if there is a specific value in it, it executes the code to retrieve the data but then automatically continues unto the next line, not waiting for the retrieval of data. I am using this code to retrieve the data:

```
self.ref.child("Period \(periodListValue)").child("Students").child("\(studentName)").child("Novel Author").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

      self.CurrentAuthorTextField.text = (snapshot.value as! String)

}
```

The line of code right below this that is not associated with the database, executes right after this code above executes. Meaning I can't use any of the database information of the code right below the one shown above.

I am trying to explain this as best as I.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to use the completion handler for the following:-

```
func ifStudentPresent(studentName: String, completionHandler: @escaping ((_ exist : Bool) -> Void)) 
{
      self.ref.child("Period \(periodListValue)").child("Students").child("\ . 
      (studentName)").child(studentName).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
      if snapshot.exists(){
                completionHandler(true)
            }else{
                print("Student Don't exist")
                completionHandler(false)
            }
        })
  }
```

Comment: Now if I try to use the func, can you provide me with an example of using it? I just don't know what to input for the completion handler part. studentName: "Bob" and the snapshot should exist. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason you might be going through this problem is related to invalid database security rules. These can easily prevent you from retrieving your desired data and synchronizing your realtime database.

Let's assume you are trying to synchronize the `ref` database reference. You need to set the correct rules *that allow reading from this database reference* - something along the lines of `".read" = true"`.

*[Warning] Please be careful with these database security rules. Incorrect rules can lead to drastically undesired behaviors, such as people illegally reading and/or writing from/into your database. A good video on how to set flawless security rules is [The key to firebase security - Google I/O 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUBnlbjZFAI)*

Answer (score 0):

```
let dispatch = DispatchGroup.init()
dispatch.enter()

self.ref.child("Period \(periodListValue)").child("Students").child("\(studentName)").child("Novel Author").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) 
in

    self.CurrentAuthorTextField.text = (snapshot.value as! String)
    dispatch.leave()
}

dispatch.notify(queue: .main) {
    //write code here, it will execute after database fetch             
}
```

Comment: Sadly I incorporated this in my code but it doesn't execute the code in the disptch.notiy(queue: .main){}. I dont really understand this but can you supply me with an understanding of how this code work?

Comment: Here once you enter(), it will make thread to wait until you get response from firebase.  Write all code in notify, which you mentioned is getting executed.